# Ghostscript: convert pdf such that every page is a single image without individual objects/text

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I would like to convert a multipage pdf with images and text such that every page is just a flat image without individual objects/text that can be selected (needed to not mess up a pdf-->ppt conversion...). It's not enough that the text can't be searched / copied (I've tried `-dNoOutputFonts`).
This command does what I want for some of the pages that contain images, but not for others with  mostly text (it seems `-dHaveTransparency=false` is key here):

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dHaveTransparency=false -dFastWebView=true -sOutputFile=out_file.pdf in_file.pdf
```

What is the magic setting here to get this behavior for all pages? (Ideally while retaining a high quality output and not blowing up the file size more than necessary ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried an experiment with good results and might be what you want:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -r600 -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Try the pdfimage24 and pdfimage32 devices as needed. There is more info here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.53.3/Devices.htm#PDFimage